# Weird vibration of car wheels when rendered - rigacar addon

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, add-on, path

I am making a low poly car animation for a school project. Since I haven't rigged a car before and dont have much time I used an addon called Rigacar for the car rig (link to addon page: http://digicreatures.net/articles/rigacar.html ). Everything looked OK when I made a simple test animation using a path untill I rendered it. When seeing the rendered result there is a weird wheel bouncing/vibration that I do not know the source of. It happens even if there is no ground sensors used with the wheels. If anyone has a solution or a suggestion that would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a WeTransfer link that includes the blender file and the render result video: https://we.tl/t-yYDxPj7cGl

Comment: Okay , so this is sus , this problem doesnt exist in viewport

Comment: but i render 30 frames from 100th to 130th frame and there is no such problem with my render

Comment: i used eevee engine

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I just started using the Rigacar addon and I found that if the origin of the wheel objects is set to the point where the parented object that is connected to the wheel armature of the Rigacar. So if any part does not share the same origin as the wheel armature causes the wheels to bounce and vibrate.